# Microsoft Azure - Getting a 404 page using custom domain with my web app

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

There's an issue with an Azure website I'm working on where I get an azure 404 page when trying to access my web app (set up with a custom domain) without www. (with www. the site works fine). NS lookup shows that when using the naked domain (infratecheng.com) the results are different than when looking up the full domain (www.infratecheng.com).
[image: NS Lookup]
<sub>(source: [cassey.org](http://www.cassey.org/nslookup.png))</sub>

The custom domain has been set up as per the instructions on the azure portal.

I wonder if this is a problem with configuration within azure or is it a problem with my domain provider settings?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm just curious if you did `A` record mapping for naked domains as mentioned here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/. I remember doing it separately for my website.

Comment: This may well be a case of the company that is handling the Domain not correctly following instructions. I thought I had mapped it for the naked domain as well but I get an error message when trying to enter the naked domain in the list of domain names. "A CNAME record pointing from infratecheng.com to infratecheng.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.infratecheng.com to awverify.infratecheng.azurewebsites.net was not found either."

Comment: I am curious however, I practiced this process with dud domain names several times and with only creating one A record that points to the correct domain and one CNAME  awerify.www with a destination of awverify.domainname.azurewebsites.net I was able to access my website with http://domainname.com. and these two records are already set up for the website I'm having problems with at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that you only added `www.infratecheng.com` as a host name for your Azure Web App, but did not add `infratecheng.com`. So when Azure gets requests to `infratecheng.com`, it doesn't know about any site that can handle them, and returns a 404.