# web app not found when I dont use www

Tags: azure

I just made a web app and pointed my custom domain (www.kuistouiuc.com) to kuistouiuc.azurewebsites.net

A Record from kuistouiuc.com to the IP address provided by azure settings

CName from www.kuistouiuc.com to kuistouiuc.azurewebsites.net

The website works fine when I type kuistouiuc.azurewebsites.net or www.kuistouiuc.com but gives me the error in the image when I try kuistouiuc.com
although the kuistouiuc.com is mapped to the IP address in the A Record

Why is this happening.I read the suggested article by the error and didn't help much as I followed exact directions

[image]

Comment: Please see if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476220/microsoft-azure-getting-a-404-page-using-custom-domain-with-my-web-app/33482284#33482284. Looks like you missed out on one configuration either in Azure or in your domain registrar.

Comment: azure doesn't allow me to add just kuistouiuc.com in the domains section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the docs claim it's enough to add A record for yourdomain.com and CNAME for *.yourdomain.com, it's not.
In addition to yourdomain.com, add www.yourdomain.com in Azure portal as well and it will work.